# Selecting DOM elements in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I'm a bit puzzled by the following: Let's say I've got a paragraph element with the id of `para`. Using Chromes console, if I say

```
document.getElementById("para")
```

I'm returned with the HTML snippet `<p id="para">....</p>`, whereas if I use for instance the Javascript library D3's selection method and say

```
d3.select("#para")
```

I'm returned with the DOM node and can access all the properties and methods of the paragraph element.

Why this difference?

Comment: What does the `select()` method return, the node or an object representing that node?

Comment: Are you sure that the first method *returns* a HTML snippet, or could it be that you're seeing the string representation of the DOM node?

Comment: @DavidThomas: part of the problem is that I don't really know the difference between the two. Is there an article or something where I can read up about those concepts?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default, when logging a DOM node in Chrome, it displays as markup. To log the DOM node as a normal object use `console.dir`. The reason `d3.select("#para")` shows as a normal object is that this method probably doesn't return a DOM node, but an object that wraps over the DOM node.

```
console.dir(document.getElementById("para"));
```

Comment: This is right answer actually, downvote is inadequate. `d3.select` returns custom object.

Comment: @dfsq, Probably got downvoted because I did not explain anything in my initial version ;)

Comment: Thank you! I will mark this answer as accepted, but just to make sure I really get it: what do you mean by an object that wraps over the DOM node?

Comment: @Vienno, DOM elements can have a different interface depending on the browser you are using which makes it very hard to write cross-browser code. E.g. IE8 doesn't support `addEventListener`. For that reason, when working with DOM nodes, most libraries (like jQuery for instance) uses an adapter object that wraps over the native DOM element and provides a unified interface so that you don't have to worry about those things.

Comment: @plalx Oh, I see. Is there any documentation or something where I can read more about this? And thanks again!

Comment: @Vienno, You can read about the [Adapter Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Answer (score 7):

The best method in my opinion is this:

- open the chrome console
- type: `$x("//input[@id='para']")`

With a click on the found element you can also see it selected